# newick format: number directly after closed parenthesis?

Tags: graph-theory, biopython, phylogeny, ggtree

I have a phylogenetic tree in Newick format. A sample from the full string looks like this:
"...(tet_rpg.hmm_GCA_000638155.1_seq1:0.001565531,tet_rpg.hmm_GCA_000507745.1_seq1:0.001565235)0.000:5e-09,...". I understand that distances are given by the number after a colon, but what do numbers immediately following closed parentheses signify? In the sample above, what does "0.000" represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bootstrap values. The confidence level of clade existence.

[Classic source](https://www.researchgate.net/deref/https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fstatistical-science%2Fvolume-18%2Fissue-2%2FApplying-the-Bootstrap-in-Phylogeny-Reconstruction%2F10.1214%2Fss%2F1063994980.pdf)

Comment: Is that necessarily true? Could not the number denote an alternative measure of clade confidence, such as posterior probability – or indeed any arbitrary clade label?

Comment: @MartinSmith Of course, yes. For instance, if we talk about BEAST and other Bayesian tools. I just gave the answer about common use.